# Getting the following error with my LSTM in R

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, r, lstm

I am getting the following error whenever I train my model in R:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()

model %>%
  layer_lstm(units=data_dim, input_shape = c(timesteps, data_dim),return_sequences=TRUE, use_bias=TRUE,dropout=0.35,recurrent_dropout=0.35) %>%
  layer_activation("linear") %>%
  layer_lstm(units=data_dim,return_sequences=TRUE, use_bias=TRUE,dropout=0.35,recurrent_dropout=0.35) %>%
  layer_activation("linear") %>%
  layer_lstm(units=5*data_dim,return_sequences=TRUE, use_bias=TRUE,dropout=0.35,recurrent_dropout=0.35) %>%
  layer_activation("linear") %>%
  layer_dense(units=out_dim,activation="linear")

optimizer <- optimizer_rmsprop(lr = 0.01)

model %>% compile(
  loss = "mean_squared_error", 
  optimizer = optimizer
)

model %>% fit(
    train_in, train_out,
    batch_size = batch_size,
    epochs = 1000)
```

> UserWarning: Method on_batch_end() is slow compared to the batch update (1.533262). Check your callbacks.

Can somebody please explain what's going on?